# If You Press No For Getting New Mii's, How do you get it back?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

When I first got SpotPass on the Mii Plaza, it asked if you wanted to get new Miis using the Internet. I accidently pressed no, and now my plaza isn't filling up good.

How can I get more miis into the plaza? There is a way to enable the internet option to get more miis?

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine if you pressed no. If you want to get more miis using Spotpass, all you have to do is go on settings and enable Spotpass. Also, make sure that you have your internet connection enabled. I hope this helped you.